# how to make item background and it's shape display together

Tags: android, selector, shapes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#996a151f" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_temp_oval">
        <shape android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#00ffffff" />
            <stroke android:width="1sp" android:color="#99a93435" />
        </shape>
    </item>
```

I want to add a border in the front of the drawable picture, but I found the border will disappear when the picture exists. Can I have the picture and border at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a layer-list http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList

I think you want to do something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_temp_oval">
        <shape android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#00ffffff" />
            <stroke android:width="1sp" android:color="#99a93435" />
        </shape>
    </item>
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#996a151f" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look that.